# In Vue, what is the meaning of #default in <template #default>?

Tags: vue.js

I'm looking at an existing Vue code base and I am seeing `<template>` tags like:

```
<template #default>
<template #content>
<template #close>
```

I know each vue component is enclosed in the `<template>` tag but I've never seen `#default` or `#content` embedded within the template tag before. What is the purpose of this? I'm suspecting those `#` are customisable but you just have to define them? If that is the case, where would I be able to find it in a vue project? I'm assuming there is a standard location to store files like this in a vue project. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`#` in a `template` tag is simply shorthand for `v-slot:`. See: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#named-slots

Answer (score 6):

The `#` is a shorthand for vue `v-slot:`. [can read a perfect example here](https://bezkoder.com/vue-v-slot/)